# How to embed Google Maps with api key from secrets - ASP .NET MVC Core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I'm using google maps in a view like [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation).
For dev purposes I have acquired dev API Key. Works fine. 
I would like to store the API Key for Google Maps and/or other APIs in application secrets. And to have it as a system parameter.
 Technically no problem with that except one problem: How to pass the key to a view?

Actually I have the script (below), which is loaded from Google (the maps+key), in the layout view. I would like to avoid have all view models inherited from a base class with the API Key.

```html
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

Since the api key is deployment specific, it makes sense to extract it to separate app section. The app is deployed in Azure, so secrets are different from dev env.
Well, technically the API Key is not a secret, but app secrets can be used prefectly for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The API key you have for maps is fine to leave in your html file as it is a browser API key. If you are still uneasy leaving it there follow [this tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/integrating-google-maps-places-and-geocode-apis-with-asp-net-mvc-5/) for integrating API keys in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Dylan makes an important point in his answer: the key will necessarily be exposed in plain text in your HTML. However, it's not a secret key. Google does recommend that you set allowed domains in the API Console, though, so other people can't just use your key on their sites and steal your API quotas.

That said, it's still a good idea to store it in some place like Application Settings, simply so you don't have to hardcode it in multiple places. If all the views just reference an App Setting, then, you can change it once for all, should you need to.

By default, Application Settings are set as internal, so they aren't available directly to views (the views are processed in a different assembly, so they aren't technically internal to your application). There's an often-missed dropdown at the top of the Application Settings screen in your project's properties. There you can switch the settings to be public if you so desire, which should allow you direct access in your view.

Alternatively, you can simply access the setting in your controller action and set something like a property on your model or a `ViewBag` member with the value. Then, you can of course access *that* in your view.

Answer (score 1):

Just have found a solution [here](https://damienbod.com/2016/07/13/injecting-configurations-in-razor-views-in-asp-net-core/).

It is about injecting instances to a view, the configuration in this case. Since MVC Core fully supports DI it is the best approach.